# Ruby - Checkbox Validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to get my checkbox validation working for my app. Basically, I enter a vehicle id number (VIN) and the system checks if there is a duplicate in the database. We want to allow the duplicate if the user clicks a checkbox to allow it.  Here is my current code:

View:

```
 .field-row
   %label VIN
   = f.text_field :vin, class:'mono-field'
 .field-row
   %label Allow Dup VIN
   = f.check_box :vincheck
```

Model:

```
 class Vehicle < ApplicationRecord
   attr_accessor :vincheck
   #this checks if the checkbox is checked
   validates_acceptance_of :vincheck, message: "Must check 'Allow Dup Vin' to save a duplicate VIN."
   #this checks for the duplicate VIN in the database
   validates :vin, uniqueness: true, :if => :vincheck
```

If I enter a duplicate VIN and don't check the checkbox I get the following errors:

```
 Vincheck Must check 'Allow Dup Vin' to save a duplicate VIN.
 Vin has already been taken
```

If I enter a valid VIN I get:

```
 Vincheck Must check 'Allow Dup Vin' to save a duplicate VIN.
```

If I enter a valid VIN and click the checkbox I don't get any errors. I need to be able to select the checkbox and leave a duplicate VIN in there.

I feel like I'm close but must be missing something. Its as if the

```
 :if => :vincheck
```

isn't actually doing anything. I thought that would have allowed me to skip out on having the validates_acceptance_of.

Any thoughts?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, just use a Proc in your "if" clause:

```
validates :vin, uniqueness: true, :unless => Proc.new { |vehicle| vehicle.vincheck? }
```

The current record is passed to the Proc, so you can check any of the attributes.

You also don't need the acceptance validation for vincheck.  That will force the box to be checked.  You should use a custom message on the `vin` validation that explains the usage of the check box.

Comment: Thanks for the info! When I try this I get this in the error.log: "undefined method 'vincheck' for #<Vehicle:0x007f61518a8d60> Did you mean? vincheck"

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that you've declared it with `attr_accessor`.  It needs to be a database field, otherwise you'll have trouble if you try to update this record.  There's another pitfall related to that which is your prior record with a certain vin would also need that to be checked.  Think hard about what you're doing here as it can lead to difficulty later.

Comment: Ah... so the checkbox needs to be a db field? I never really intended on saving that - but if it needs to be there to work guess I'll need to add it. The checkbox was the only way I thought I could get around showing the user that there was a duplicate vin but still allowing them to save. Is there a way to maybe tell them there is a duplicate vin and just save it anyway (bypassing the validation check)?

Comment: Ok... I added vincheck as a column (and disabled attr_accessor) to the Vehicle table and initially defaulted the values to "1". However, I now never get the val error that there are duplicates. I tried changing the db values to "0" to see if that made a difference and it did not... still don't get a val error that there are duplicates.

Comment: You're getting beyond the scope of StackOverflow.

Comment: I thought the goal of StackOverflow was to help developers so not sure how I was going beyond the scope?  Anyway... I finally got it working by doing, "validates :vin, uniqueness: true, :unless => Proc.new { |vehicle| vehicle.vincheck == '1' }" Since the value in the db was preset to 1 it checks against that. I'll accept your answer since you got me down the path of putting it in the db.

Comment: SO is for answering programming questions.  At some point, you're seeking help in debugging, which isn't really what SO is for.  Please see here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

You have added acceptance validation, due to which acceptance is get check each time, irrespective of vin number,

please try following solution, this will show acceptance error message only if vincheck id failed.

```
class Vehicle < ApplicationRecord

  attr_accessor :vincheck

    validates_acceptance_of :vincheck, 
                            message: "Must check 'Allow Dup Vin' to save a duplicate VIN.",
                            :if => :vincheck_fail?

    validates               :vin, uniqueness: true, :unless => :vincheck        

    def vincheck_fail?
        self.vin.present? && Vehicle.where('vin = ? AND id != ?', self.vin, self.id).present?
    end

end
```

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I gave it a shot but get, "Vin has already been taken". I never see the "Must check 'Allow Dup Vin" message. When I click the checkbox.. the error message stays and wont let me submit with a duplicate vin. Any thoughts? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I finally got it working. I added vincheck into the database and preset the values to 1. Here is the code that does the check:

```
 validates :vin, uniqueness: true, :unless => Proc.new { |vehicle| vehicle.vincheck == '1' }
```

Thanks to @Michael Chaney for the Proc and db suggestions.